# Midnight commander тормозит при открытии файлов?

Tags: freebsd

FreeBSD 10. MC стоит из портов. Собран с subshell, iconv, slang. При открытии файла даже на 300-400 кб размером он думает с минуту, причем хоть на чтение, хоть на редактирование. Если открывать через тот же nano, то все ок. 
Уже пеересобирал его, не помогло. Что можно еще сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема может быть с механизмами определения типов файлов и способа работы с ними. Если так, то смотреть нужно в сторону /usr/local/share/mc/mc.ext и /usr/share/misc/magic.

Как решение - кто-то меняет /usr/share/misc/magic на более старую версию (из 6.2), кто-то удаляет /usr/local/share/mc/mc.ext.

*Добавка:*

Ещё на https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/usr-bin-file-works-very-slow.52958/ рекомендуют:

```
I delete /usr/bin/file and link /usr/local/bin/file (from ports) to /usr/bin, now MC again quickly open large files.
```

Короче, sysutils/file там сломался чего-то в 10.2

Comment: а вот у себя я такого не нашел  /usr/local/share/mc/mc.ext

Comment: >>/usr/bin/file and link /usr/local/bin/file (from ports) to /usr/bin
Вот это помогло, спасибо.